# Pull out text within specific divs on a webpage

Tags: web-scraping, go

I am looking for some guidance and feedback on my first golang program. The language is very new to me and its been a long while since I have written anything close to C.

Below is a simple program that takes a url and looks for divs within the page containing a specific class. Once found I read the text within the div outputting it to the terminal.

I am looking for general feedback especially on my use of pointers and slices, the way I am getting the text out of the div (in a loop with a bool variable) which seems a bit hacky to me

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "sort"

    "golang.org/x/net/html"
)

// Helper function to identify if the token is an image div
func isImageDiv(token html.Token) (ok bool) {
    // Iterate over all of the Token's attributes until we find "class"
    for _, a := range token.Attr {
        if a.Key == "class" {
            // The image labels are surrounded by div with the class "project-title"
            if a.Val == "project-title" {
                ok = true
                return
            }
        }
    }

    // "bare" return will return the variables (ok) as defined in
    // the function definition
    return
}

func getLabel(z *html.Tokenizer) (label string) {
    return string(z.Text())
}

func crawl(url string, foundLabels *[]string) {
    resp, err := http.Get(url)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("ERROR: Failed to crawl \"" + url + "\"")
        return
    }

    b := resp.Body
    defer b.Close() // close Body when the function returns

    z := html.NewTokenizer(b)

    readText := false
    for {
        tt := z.Next()

        switch {
        case tt == html.ErrorToken:
            // End of the document, we're done
            return
        case tt == html.StartTagToken:
            t := z.Token()

            // Check if the token is an <div> tag
            isDiv := t.Data == "div"
            if !isDiv {
                continue
            }

            // Verify that is has the class we are looking for, if there is one
            ok := isImageDiv(t)
            if !ok {
                continue
            }
            readText = true
        case tt == html.TextToken && readText == true:
            *foundLabels = append(*foundLabels, getLabel(z))
            readText = false
        }
    }
}

func main() {

    url := ""

    foundLabels := make([]string, 0)

    crawl(url, &foundLabels)

    sort.Strings(foundLabels)

    for _, element := range foundLabels {
        // element is the element from someSlice for where we are
        fmt.Println(element)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all: how big is this document? If you're not expecting it to be big, you may want to use [html.Parse](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/net/html#Parse) instead of a tokenizer - that way, you'll get the whole document in a tree and would be able to iterate over children of your div when found, which should make the whole thing simpler.

Your current approach is streaming, which conserves memory, but you are making the assumption that the div with the class `project-title` will always contain just text. What if the document looks like this:

```
<div class="project-title"><div>not title</div>title</div>
```

or this

```
<div class="project-title"></div><div>wrong title</div>
```

In the first case, "not title" would be added. In the second, "wrong title" would be added.

---

Assuming you want to keep your logic as-is, let's move on the review!

A few general tips:

- Always put string literals on top as constants (e.g. `const className = "project-title"`).
- You don't need to name your return values unless you see a need.
- While Go values brevity, `z` is (almost) never a good variable name.
- Most of the comments don't add any value (e.g. "Check if the token is an <div> tag").

Some specific things:

- In `isImageDiv`, you don't need a separate `if` block. You also don't need to name the return value, which actually simplifies your code in this case. Finally, you should also check if the element is a div - that way, you needn't do it in `crawl`:

  ```
  func isImageDiv(token html.Token) bool {
      if token.Data != "div" {
          return false
      }
      for _, a := range token.Attr {
          if a.Key == "class" && a.Val == "project-title" {
              return true
          }
      }
      return false
  }
  ```
- `getLabel` seems too simple to have a need to exist.
- In `crawl`, you shouldn't use `fmt.Println`. Instead, return an `error`, the same way `http.Get` returns it. Let the caller handle it.
- In `crawl`, you can simplify the `switch` a lot - `continue` is not really needed and we made our `isImageDiv` function do the div check as well:

  ```
  switch tt {
  case html.ErrorToken:
      return
  case html.StartTagToken:
      if isImageDiv(z.Token()) {
          readText = true
      }
  case html.TextToken:
      if readText {
          *foundLabels = append(*foundLabels, getLabel(z))
          readText = false
      }
  }
  ```
- In `main`, you don't need to use `make` for a slice since the default value for a slice is an empty slice (you can just define it as `var foundLabels []string` and it will just work). Also, you shouldn't pass the slice as a pointer - slices are passed by reference anyway (not really, but due to [the nature of how they work](https://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals), they're already pointers). Make sure you change your `crawl` function as well after that.